# How to make sure your contract is receiving ETH

Tags: solidity

I'm playing around with a test contract & am learning how to transfer & hold funds. I currently have a pool set up, which is set to receive ETH & nothing else. However, when writing my first test to check the pool, my mappings (how I'm keeping tabs on balances for testing sake) are updating, but my function to check the pool balance keeps returning zero.

Am I doing something wrong here, or am I completely missing something? Any help here would be much appreciated, been at it all day with minimal results. Relevant code here:

Contract:

```
contract Pool {
  mapping(address => uint256) public stakerAmt;

  function stake(uint256 _amount, address payable _from) public payable {
    _amount = _amount * 1 ether;
    stakerAmt[_from] += _amount;
    payable(address(this)).transfer(msg.value);
  }

  function getPoolBalance() public view returns (uint256) {
    console.log("Contract balance: ", address(this).balance);
    return address(this).balance;
  } 

}
```

Test:

```
describe('Pool', function () {
    it('Should accept staked eth', async function () {
        const Pool = await ethers.getContractFactory('Pool');
        const pool = await Pool.deploy();
        await pool.deployed();

        const [user] = await ethers.getSigners();

        const stake = await pool.connect(user).stake(20, user.address);

        await stake.wait();
        console.log(stake);
        console.log(await pool.getPoolBalance().toString());

        assert.equal(20, 20);
    });
```

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Remix?! Does your contract work well on Remix?! in solidity we don't have `console.log()`, is it a function you declared?!

Function you want to write, it is not written well! I'll show a better one:

```
//You do not need those parameters
function stake() public payable {
  //Here you make sure caller sends some ETH.
  require(msg.value >= PRICE_YOU_WANT, "You did not send enough ETH");

  //Add stake amount into the stakerAmt by the caller address. msg.value is in wei and you
  //store it in wei because other paying functions also are in wei (for example address.transfer)
  stakerAmt[msg.sender] += msg.value;
  
  //Then you do not need those functions! Because when the caller calls this function
  //it automatically send ETH! So those functions are not usefull!
}
```

Comment: I do use Remix, but I'm just using my normal code editor for this. I imported the console.log from hardhat which gives me that functionality (works great!). The amount of ETH itself is not the problem, it's mainly the fact that I cannot access the correct balance in the getPoolBalance method, even though the first part of the test (staking & how much is staked) is passing. I want to make sure that the contract is in fact receiving the ETH, since not only does returning the balance equal zero but I also am not seeing any test ether leaving my hardhat account with each test.

Comment: Try now and tell me if it works or not. Also try more Remix and use testnets (Personally I use Rinkeby). If it works on Remix and testnets, it is 99% guaranteed to work on other chains!